# Using a password to protect private key in c++

Tags: c++, encryption, private-key

I'm planning to write a little application with the basic idea that users are able to share encrypted information with each other. A little scenario: Alice writes a memo (data format is known), the application encrypts this memo and saves the memo on the application server. Now Alice wants to share this memo with Bob. Alice opens the application, searches for user "Bob" and receives the public key of Bob. The application encrypts the memo with Alice and Bob's key and saves the memo on the server. Now Bob is also able to read the memo.

The private key of the user only belongs to the device where the application is installed. It is never transferred over network. Nevertheless I would like to 'encrypt' the private key with the password of the user, so it can be stored in a (relative) secure way on the device and only be 'decrypted' if the correct password is entered. The key itself should not be altered if the password of the user changes, because this would cause that all data will have to be encrypted again with this new key. Instead the user will have to enter the old passphrase, the key is decrypted and encrypted again with the new passphrase.

Is there any function (maybe in OpenSSL?) to 'encrypt' or protect a key with a passphrase?

Note: the private key may or may not be stored in a keystore. because the application will run on many plattforms it is not clear in advance which keystore is available.

Comment: You're redesigning PGP/GPG. So yes, such systems already exist and you shouldn't try to rewrite them and expect them to be secure ;)

Comment: The concise, but full answer is: Yes. The verbous answer is: There are libraries that provide a function or several for encrypting text.

Comment: let's assume it wouldn't be such a trivial application. Is it possible to integrate PGP in my own applications?

Comment: @YSC, not only OP is redesigning GPG, they are copy-pasting the examples from GPG manual ;)

Comment: @SergeyA OP could very well be quoting an assignment given by a teacher who copy-pasted the example from GPG manual :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to integrate PGP in my own applications?

[*GnuPG Made Easy* (GPGME)](https://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/) "is a library designed to make access to GnuPG easier for applications. It provides a High-Level Crypto API for encryption, decryption, signing, signature verification and key management."

Comment: And OP should be very well aware of this, since the question is a copy-paste from GPG manual.

Comment: It isn't and I wasn't. The answer of YSC and DevSolar where very helpfull because they preserved me from running into one of the most common 'newbe' problems in cryptography. I guess this is a case of 'never implement your own ...'

Answer (score 3):

Using `OpenSSL` you can save your key in a protected form (`BEGIN RSA ENCRYPTED...`). An exemplary function you may want to use (I'm omiting all the operations required beforehand, but they're pretty elementary).

```
PEM_write_PKCS8PrivateKey(pFile, m_pKey, cipher, sPass, iPassLen, 0, NULL)
```

where `cipher` is your encryption algorithm, of appropriate type. More (with examples!) here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/pem.html